# Document Center and Existing Document Library

Tags: 2013, records-center

I am currently testing migration of Sharepoint 2010 to 2013, especially focused on document management.

I have added a document center on this new site. Is there a way to link this into the existing document libraries people have added (there are a number of these all in different departments).

What is best practice for this? Do I setup a document center for each department? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `Is there a way to link this into the existing document libraries people have added ?`

You can achieve that by building a retention policy as the following based on your requirements.

- You can create a retention policy definition within your site collection, then apply that policy to content types throughout the site.
- You can create a retention policy that’s associated with a content type that’s defined in the root of the site collection.
- You can create a retention policy that’s associated with a local content type that has been applied to a list or library.
- You can create a retention policy directly on a list or library itself.

Check also [How to Create and apply information management policies](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-apply-information-management-policies-eb501fe9-2ef6-4150-945a-65a6451ee9e9)

Regarding `Do I setup a document center for each department`?

It also depends on your data size requirements , But I recommend if you don't have big data size. try to create only document center for all department that will hold content up to 4 TB for your web application. this will lead to avoid performance issue and multiple database maintenance ... etc .

- See also the [Consideration of content database for Document Center](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ContentDB)
- See also [Plan document management in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263266.aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much will read through those. Also when I create automatic document ID despite me putting a totally different prefix (in begin IDs with)...I am getting FFEDT24UCARV-2-(Document number).

Comment: So by sounds of it creating a document center for each department might be the way to go. We have fairly small document numbers, is it possible to convert these existing document librarys into document centers? (i.e. what is best way to bring this information across from old site to new (which will use document center as opposed to document library))

Comment: Document center should be used for archiving big number of document files based on a specific policy, ans also considered an option  to overcome the content database limit 200 GB , so why you need to use it if you have a small document number

Comment: I think the entire site is well under 50GB content wise currently. However we are considering moving from a traditional file network share (currently 225gb) to making everything available to each department via SharePoint (document library or document center) we also want to implement some type of record/document management.